# Mocha is throwing Promise rejection error in Test expect error condition. How to fix this?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm using Mocha and Chai for unit tests. My test case looks like below.

```js
describe('1. Users APIs', () => {
    it('1.1 Get Users', (done) => {
        controller.getCaseDetails(req, res, () => { }).then(data => {
            except(data).to.be.have.property(statusCode, 400);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

If the test case fails then I'm getting below error.

```
  1) 1. Users APIs.
       1.1 Get Users:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/home/techjini/Techjini/node-projects/CollectionsApp-NodeJS/src/cases/test/getCases.test.js)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

To fix this I have added `.catch` to then block and `done()` inside catch. Then the test got succeeded. how to fix this issue.

As per my backtrack I got that If I add catch block then the error is handled and but mocha wont get any Assertion errors If I'm not wrong.

I want to print proper error message in-case of `except` failure.

Any kind of help will much be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set timeout for async requests as below:

```
describe('Live Agent', function () {
    //set timeout for this test suit
    this.timeout(25000);
    describe('createRequest', function () {
        it(" Live agent request is created", function (done) {
            supertestAgent
                .post(apiPath + "/createRequest")
                .send({
                    "dialogId": "5e427fc25c790ffa5c727a",
                    "platform": "fb",
                    "endUser": { id: "fsfg" }
                })
                .end(function (err, result) {
                    expect(err).equals(null);
                    expect(result.status).equals(201)
                    done();
                });
        })
    });
```

In above code sample, timeout is set to top container so that all the test cases below that will inherit timeout.

```
this.timeout(25000)
```

Moacha directly prints the assertion error, so we don't get access to it.So, you need add more test cases while preventing `expect` failure.